# Firefox Extension executeAsync Returns only 15 rows at a time

Tags: sqlite, firefox-addon, istorage

I am developing a firefox extension which reads and writes to a sqlite database. I ran an async query to fetch 20 rows from a database, and the callback function which handles the receipt of data gets called twice. The first time it return 15 rows and second time it return the last 5. Is this a standard value? If so, can this value be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `executeAsync` will return a result after at most 15 rows and 75ms execution time. No, this cannot be changed - the thresholds are [hardcoded](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/9a230265bad5/storage/src/mozStorageAsyncStatementExecution.cpp#l61).

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying that it will be one of the two conditions, which ever happens first? As in if 75ms have passed before 15 records are received, it will still return the records it has received to this point?

Comment: Yes, looks like it. I didn't really look into this code however, only found the constants.